# Order Array by Relevant Search Results

Tags: php, search

I know that there has to be a library for this somewhere, but what I am trying to do is pass in an array of strings, and a search string and have it order the array by how relevant it is to the search string.

I have been having a hard time figuring out what to google to figure this out, anyone point me in the right direction?

preferably in php, or another server side language

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) And define *relevant*.

Comment: what do you mean by how relevant? Similar, or relevant with respect to a criteria you have?

Comment: This is a trick question. There is no subjective array filter.

Comment: I have tried looking through google but wasn't able to find what I was looking for. And by relevant I just mean close, as in a search for apple might come up with "Fuji apple" "red apple" etc. Also similar spellings like aple might come up with apple results still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you mean by 'revelant'..

But, if you want to find the best string based on a search string, you can use the Levenshtein algorithm. It calculate a "distance" between two strings.

More infos here : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.levenshtein.php

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda tricky and I cannot really explain in English, so I'll just have to show you a working code. If you have an questions, you can ask.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <title>Search Array</title>
      <script>
      //so let's set an array of values we will be searching

    function searchArray(dis) {

        var bigContent = new Array('Jesus loves you','Angle','God in Heaven','Bala','Overcomer','Be born again','Adesuwa','Heaven is real','James','Apple','John the baptist');//this is the array that serves as your database

        var searchi = dis.value, result = Array();
        searchi = searchi.toLowerCase();

        //order the array alphabetically
        bigContent = bigContent.sort();

        var content;

        if(searchi !='') {
            //Define the arrays for initial pre-storage
            var keys = new Array(), contentArray = new Array();

            //Loop through the content array to search for all occurence of string
            for(var i=0;i<bigContent.length;i++) {
                content = bigContent[i].toLowerCase();
                if(content.indexOf(searchi) > -1) {//found the search in this value
                    //get the position of the search string in content
                    var pos = content.indexOf(searchi);

                    //make position the key for your content array
                    if(contentArray[pos]) {//check if this position has already been assigned to a content
                        //if yes, append this content.
                        contentArray[pos] += '[]'+bigContent[i];
                    } else {//else, set the content
                        contentArray[pos] = bigContent[i];
                        //only save the position the first time you find it, to avoid duplication
                        keys[keys.length] = pos;
                    }
                }
            }
            //sort the key so it can order the values in ascending order(relevance)
            keys = keys.sort();

            //loop thru the key
            for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++) {
                var key = keys[i];//remember the value of "var key" is the key for contentArray value
                if(contentArray[key]) {//just to be sure it's ther
                    var thisContent = contentArray[key];
                    //check if the content has more than 1 value
                    if(thisContent.indexOf('[]') < 0) {//if it doesn't
                        result[result.length] = contentArray[key];
                    } else {//if it does
                        //convert content into array
                        var thisContentAr = thisContent.split('[]');
                        //Loop thru the array
                        for(var j=0;j<thisContentAr.length;j++) {
                            result[result.length] = thisContentAr[j];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('ov').innerHTML = '';
        for(var i = 0; i<result.length;i++) {
            document.getElementById('ov').innerHTML += '<div>'+result[i]+'</div>';
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div><input type="text" onkeyup="searchArray(this);" autofocus="autofocus" /></div>
    <div id="ov"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```